# For the given space X determine whether the subset A is closed or open (or neither). find interior of A and closure of A.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For the given space X determine whether the subset A is closed or open (or neither). find the interior of A and closure of A.

X = [0; 1], A is the set of numbers that can be written without using the digits 1 and 8 in their decimal expansions.

I try to write A as an intersection or union to solve question but ı cannot write such set.

Comment: $X$ is a metric space, so you could use sequences to tell if a set is closed or open. That is, a subset $A\subseteq X$ is closed if all sequences $(x_n)\subseteq A$ which converge, converge to a point also in $A$.

Comment: Start with intersecting by [0,.1) cup (.1,.8) cup  (.8,1] and repeat for each portion somewhat like what is done for the Cantor set.

Comment: Usual topology on X?

Answer (score 0):

The interior is empty because any open interval will contain numbers with  a 1 and/or an 8 in the decimal expansion.

Answer (score 0):

(1). Let $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be any decimal  representation of $x\in X.$ If $x_i\in \{1,8\}$  and if $x_j\ne  9$ for some (any) $j>i$ then any representation $(x'_n)_n$ of $x$ must have $x'_i=x_i,$ and we have $x\not \in A.$

(2).For a representation $(y_n)_n$  of $y\in A $ and for $j\in \Bbb N$ let $(z_n)_n$ represent the number $f(j),$ where $z_n=y_n$ when $n\not \in \{j,j+1\}$ and $z_j=z_{j+1}=8$. By (1), $f(j)\in X$ \ $A.$

Now $|y-f(j)|<10^{1-j}$ so $y\in Cl(\{f(j):j\in \Bbb N\}\subset Cl(X \setminus A)).$ So  $X$ \ $A$ is not closed.

Therefore A is not open.

(3). Let  $(x_n)_n$ be a representation of $x\in X$ \ $A.$ Let $k$ be the least (left-most) $n$ such that $x_n\in \{1,8\}.$ Then we cannot have $x_j=9$ for all $j>k.$ Otherwise we could replace $x_k$ by $1+x_k$ and replace $x_j$ by $0$ for every $j>k$ and get a representation of $x$ with no $1$ or $8,$ implying $x\in A.$

So let $k'$ be the least (or any) $i>k$ such that $x_i\ne 9.$ Now if $y\in X$ and $|y-x|<10^{(-1-k')}$ then by (1)we have $y\in X.$  In other words  $X\cap (x-10^{(-1-k')}, x+10^{(-1-k')})\subset $X \ $A.$ So $X$ \ $A$ is open.

Therefore $A$ is closed.